# > No signature of method

Tags: android-studio

I'm trying to build a handwritten digital classifier app but the build.gradle is not syncing so I am wondering what to do. I tried multiple options but unfortunately none have worked.

```
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
    apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'

    android {
        compileSdkVersion 30
        defaultConfig {
            applicationId "org.tensorflow.lite.codelabs.digitclassifier"
            minSdkVersion 21
            targetSdkVersion 30
            versionCode 1
            versionName "1.0"
            testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        }

        // TODO: Add an option to avoid compressing TF Lite model file
          aapOptions {
            noCompress "tflite"
        }

        buildTypes {
            release {
                minifyEnabled false
                proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-androidb optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
            }
        }
    }

    // Sanity check if you have trained and downloaded TF Lite model.
    preBuild.doFirst {
        assert file("./src/main/assets/mnist.tflite").exists() :
                "mnist.tflite not found. Make sure you have trained and " +
                        "downloaded your TensorFlow Lite model to assets/ folder"
    }

    dependencies {
        implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
        implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"

        // Support Libraries
        implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.3.0'
        implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.5.0'
        implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.0.4'

        // AndroidDraw Library
        implementation 'com.github.divyanshub024:AndroidDraw:v0.1'

        // Task API
        implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-tasks:17.2.1"

        //TODO: Add TF Lite
        implementation 'org.tensorflow:tensorflow-lite:2.7.0'


        testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.3.0'
        androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.3.0'
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. I have tried changing some of the SDK tools but that hasn't worked either. I don't know what I am going to do to make it sync up

Comment: You mention a fraction of an error message in your title, but didn't post the rest in your question. Please [edit] your question to include the full error message.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo. `aapOptions` should be `aaptOptions`.

Also the `proguardFiles` has a problem and you'll get a more clear error message about it.